Preserving image/video captioned text moving from iPhone to offline storage
On photos and videos I paste the descriptions and links in the Caption field in the iPhone Photos app.
Videos that I then send from my iPhone to my MacBook using Airdrop retain this captioned information which is visible in a “Description” field in the finder Get Info on the file.
For still images such as PNG and JPG this captioned information which information is lost. I want to preserve these comments. The setting to preserve comments before sending the files is ignored.
iCloud does retain this caption information, as I can view this caption in the web browser when logged into iCloud. Downloading the images does not preserve the comments.
Is there a third party app or other process that will preset this caption metadata stored I can archive media?
